# What is NS URI in EMF?

Tags: java, eclipse-emf

I generated some classes using EMF and now I want to instantiate them. I've created the xmi files associated with the model and metamodel. Now I want to load the model as an instance in my program, but it keeps throwing a NullPointerException.

My code is:

```
Map<String,Object> registry = EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE;
String workflowURI = ExcelEditorPackage.eNS_URI;
System.out.println(workflowURI);
ExcelEditorPackage wfPackage = (ExcelEditorPackage) registry.get(workflowURI); //throw NPE here
ExcelEditorFactory wfFactory = wfPackage.getExcelEditorFactory();
Page workflow = wfFactory.createPage();
```

It throws an at wfFactory because wfPackage is null. My NS URI is "http://www.sg/model" (this URL does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

NS URI means namespace URI. That is the xml equivalent of packages in java. Apparently EMF runtime is unable to load the package associated with the URI you have specified. Check if URI you are specifying is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> It throws an at wfFactory because wfPackage is null.

If the NPE is really thrown at the line you indicate, it *cannot* be happening because `wfPackage` is `null`.  In fact, it must indicate that `registry` is `null`.

> My NS URI is "http://www.sg/model" (this URL does not exist).

That shouldn't matter.  The NS URI is just a "unique name" that denotes the XML Namespace for your model.  It doesn't have to be resolvable.